# Counting the number of ways in which an integer can be written as a sum of other two integers belonging to two different finite sets.

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I am trying to count the number of ways in which I can write a given $l = 1,.., a+b$ as $l = j+m$ where $j = 1, .., a$ and $m = 0, .. ,b$. I suppose partitions could be used to solve the problem, but I am not an expert of those and do not really know how to use them properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would start with some examples ... Certainly the number is not larger than $\min (a, b)$.

Comment: If you know $l$ and chose $j$, how many options are there for $m$?

Comment: Is not $l=1$ impossible?

Comment: Yes $l=1$ was impossible, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) the number of ways to write a number l as a sum of two positive numbers is:
$$
\binom{l-2+(2-1)}{2-1}=\binom{l-1}1.
$$
From this number we should subtract the number of combinations with $j>a$ and $m>b$, which are
$$
\binom{l-a-1}1\quad\text{and}\quad   \binom{l-b-1}1,
$$
respectively. Fol $l>a+b$ this would however double count the expressions with both $j>a$ and $m>b$. Therefore by [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) the final result valid for any $l>0$ is:
$$
\binom{l-1}1-\binom{l-a-1}1-\binom{l-b-1}1+\binom{l-a-b-1}1,
$$
with the convention $\binom nk=0$ if $n<0$, so that the expression can be written as:
$$
l-1-\max(0,l-a-1)-\max(0,l-b-1)+\max(0,l-a-b-1).
$$

Comment: Isn't the final result identically zero ?

Comment: For $l>a+b$ the final result is identically zero. As well as for $l=0,1$. Otherwise it is non-zero.